# Auto Increment (identity) each year in Invoice Number

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have one App in VB.net and SQL Server database. My Table Have Column ID, Date, and Invoice Number, etc

I have Format 1/2022 and next is 2/2022 what generate from ID, But my problem is How to Reset again in new Year in 1 example 1/2023.

How Can I fix this. Thank You.

Comment: Invoices usually have an emission date. Look at that date and you know the year. Is this a multiuser application? I mean, do you have more than one user responsible for invoice processing?

Comment: You can use a sequence rather than an identity and then you can reset it.

Comment: Yes is MultiUser so is Online SQL Server.

Comment: A sequence would work but you have to remember to reset it every year. I would ask why you need this. That is a non-standard way of creating invoice numbers. I know that sometimes for tax purposes you need incremental numbers but your format isn't an actual number so not sure it would work correct anyway. I would think that just an identity for your invoice number would be easier.

Comment: Presumably the ID column is the primary key - so "resetting" it will not work. You would need a composite primary key containing a column for year and a column for this "sequence" value.